# How to update a mongo nested array in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, mongoose, mern

Here is my model:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    given_name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    picture: { type: String },
    id: { type: String },
    shelf: [{ readlist: [String] }]
})
```

Inside a user's shelf, there is another array called readlist. This will be updated everytime an user add a book to his readlist.
I tried the following way when creating a user:

```
User.create({ email: email, given_name: given_name, picture: picture, id: sub, shelf: {readlist: []} });
```

But it is creating an object inside the shelf array.
How to create a readlist array directly inside the shelf array and add the values inside the readlist?

Comment: Is your shelf an array on purpose?

Comment: Yes, I hope to have reading list, to-be-read list, & readlist inside it.

Comment: So, I thought it'd be a nice idea to have them organized.